# Optimization in python returns guessed values for large numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, scipy

I want to solve an optimization problem in python. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def solve(tupleList, a_float, b_float, c_float, *, debug=False, formatStr = '%s'):

    def objective(x, sign= -1.0):
        total = 0
        for xi, pooli in zip(x, tupleList):
            Li, fi = pooli
            total += (xi + Li)*(1 - math.exp((-1)*a_float*b_float*(1-fi)*xi/(xi+Li)))
        total += (c_float - sum(x))*(1 - math.exp((-1)*a_float*b_float))
        total *= sign
        return total

    def constraint1(x, sign= -1.0):
        return sign*(sum(x) - c_float)

    n = len(tupleList)
    x0 = np.ones(n) * c_float/(n+1)  # Initial guess
    if debug:
        print('Initial Objective: {formatStr}'.format(formatStr=formatStr) % objective(x0))

    b = (0,c_float)
    bnds = (b,) * n
    con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1} 
    cons = ([con1])
    solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',\
                            bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)  
    x = solution.x

    if debug:
        # show final objective
        print('Final Objective:   {formatStr}'.format(formatStr=formatStr) % objective(x))

        # print solution
        print('Solution')
        for n, xi in enumerate(x):
            print('l_%d    = {formatStr}'.format(formatStr=formatStr) % (n, xi))
        print(    'l_rem = {formatStr}'.format(formatStr=formatStr) % (c_float - sum(x)))   

    if solution.success:
        x = np.append(x,(c_float - sum(x)))
        return x

    return None
```

If I call the function as follows, the optimization seems to work fine

```
>>> solve([(8.762E+5, 0.04), (5816E+2, 0.025), (1.5E+2, 0.015)], 7E-05, 103086,1E+0,debug=True)
Initial Objective: -5.507040251221752
Final Objective:   -7.043360870993145
Solution
l_0    = 0.0
l_1    = 0.7846865050106637
l_2    = 0.2153134949835263
l_rem = 5.810019132468369e-12
array([0.00000000e+00, 7.84686505e-01, 2.15313495e-01, 5.81001913e-12])
```

But if I use larger scale numbers (I just multiply the inputs by 1E+13) then the code just returns the initial guessed values (provided in the # Initial guess line)

```
>>> solve([(8.762E+18, 0.04), (5816E+15, 0.025), (1.5E+15, 0.015)], 7E-05, 103086,1E+13,debug=True)
Initial Objective: -55070402512217.52
Final Objective:   -55070402512217.52
Solution
l_0    = 2500000000000.0
l_1    = 2500000000000.0
l_2    = 2500000000000.0
l_rem = 2500000000000.0
array([2.5e+12, 2.5e+12, 2.5e+12, 2.5e+12])
```

Can someone provide an idea on how to get this working for large numbers such as 1E+18?

Comment: Numerical optimization algorithms are sensitive to scaling. Badly scaled problems can lead to bad results. Some advanced solvers do automatic scaling, but SLSQP is not one of them. That means: you are responsible for proper scaling of the problem.

Comment: Of course, not providing gradients will cause the algorithm to do finite differences. This will greatly increase numerical issues when a problem is poorly scaled. One should always provide gradients (unless there is an overriding reason not to so).

Comment: Ok so optimization problems are not my area, and I found the SLSQP solution by googling, without knowing it can't handle problems in a large scale. I saw there are many other solvers but I'm not sure which one will work for such large numbers and how to convert my code to them. Basically I want to minimize the value of the sum (denoted by the variable total) under constraint1 and for positive values.

Comment: Large scale means: many variables. This is not the same as poorly scaled. Numbers like 1e12 are just crazy especially when doing finite differences. Floating point numbers do not have enough precision to handle these,  I would suggest to use different units. E.g. instead of grams use megatons. I would also encourage you to talk to your teacher. This is kind of an important issue, and any user of numerical algorithms should have at least some familiarity with these concepts.

Comment: I understand that dividing the input by some constant number (which equals to changing units) would obviously solve the issue (as my first example works fine). However, in some cases I can't do this because the numbers in the input would range from 1e0 to 1e8. (I don't have a teacher (?), this code is part of a project of mine based on published research that is irrelevant with optimization algorithms)